# Julia | Population of Array

Tags: julia

I would like to make a question, regarding the population of an array Arr1 from another array Arr2.

```
Arr1 = Array{Float64, 2}(100, 220)
Arr2 = Array{Float64, 2}(100, 1100)
```

Arr2 is associated with an array index that goes like this [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 ...] and if the index is the same it adds up the elements of the previous same index.

The last value of Arr2 that corresponds to the last same index are pushed or appended to Arr1 elements in the 2nd dimension, after the 11 element except when the 3rd dimension is 12, 23, 34, 45 ...

I cannot even do a MWE, since I am very new to Julia. I hope that somebody will help.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Λ

Comment: Please add examples about what Arr1 and Arr2 contain. As it is, it's very unclear what you're asking. (For eg both your arrays are 2D, but you mention "3rd dimension" in the text.) If you don't know how to start coding the solution, that's fine, but give a MWE of what the data in the arrays might look like.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to populate values from one array (a smaller one) to another array (bigger one). Have a look below (I provide both REPL command and their results):

In the command below `Int64` and the number of dimensions can be skipped
`julia> small=Array{Int64,2}([1 2;3 4])
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4`

A good way to create prepopulated array is by using `zeros` and `ones` functions
`julia> large = zeros(Int64,4,4)
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0`

And this is the way to copy data from one array to another

`julia> large[1:2,1:2]=small;
julia> large
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  0  0
 3  4  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0`